# Volume of solid revolution against a line

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

If an Area is bounded by two curves $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\frac{x}{2}$, and it is revolved wrt to the line $x=-1$, then the Volume can be calculated using Ring method as this way? :
$$ V = \pi \int_{0}^{2} (2y+1)^{2} - (y^{2}+1)^{2} dy $$
By inverting the two bounding curves first. The key is knowing the *radius* and the orientation of the *Riemann rectangles*, is this correct..?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Notice that what you are doing, using the ring method, is the same as using the disk method to determine the volume of the figure created by rotating $y= \sqrt{x}$, from x= 0 to 2, around y= -1, then using the disk method to determine the volume of the figure created by rotating $y= x/2$, from x= 0 to 2, around y= -1, then **subtracting** the second from the first.

Comment: @Arief Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, as an alternative by shell method

$$V = 2\pi \int_{0}^{4} (x+1)(\sqrt x-x/2) dx=2\pi\left[\frac25x^{\frac52}-\frac{x^3}3+\frac23x^{\frac32}-\frac{x^2}4\right]_0^4=\frac{104\pi}5$$